# Android - How to add Google Map Marker Label?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to add a label to Google Map Marker.
I have already added Title to the Marker which is show on tap.That label contains dynamic values and it should be visible always.Just like

[image]

How can I do with Android?

Comment: make an xml file with marker and textView dynamiclly add the text to text view

Comment: What API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

JUST try this,

```
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
```